# How to copy data from a column of a data frame to another data frame using common column as a reference?

Tags: python, excel, dataframe

Assume,

- There is a dataframe[df_acc] consist of columns[Account_No,Phone_No]
- Another dataframe[df_addr] which consists of columns
  [Account_No,City,State,Phone]

Here, I want to get Phone numbers from column[Phone_no] into dataframe [df_addr],column['Phone'] using Account_No as reference.

I tried doing it and it is successfully extracting the values.

My Code:

```
if (len(df_addr>0)):
    for i in df_addr['Account_No'].index:
        v_acc_no = df_addr['Account_No'][i]
        mask = df_acc['Account_No'].isin([v_acc_no])
        if (len(df_acc[mask])>0):
           for x in df_acc[mask].index:
                 df_addr['Phone'][i] = df_acc['Phone_No'][x]
```

But, Is there any way to make this code even better?

Answer (score 1):

So you just need [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df_addr.merge(df_acc, on='Account_No')
```

You can add, `how='left'` to keep all the records from `df_addr` even though they don't have match in `df_acc` as the default is `'inner'` (intersection).

As it was mentioned in comments, `left_on` and `right_on` should be used if the columns don't share the same name.

Comment: Thanks zipa, What if the Column name is different.                                          for eg: Account_No and Acct_no

Comment: Use `df_addr.merge(df_acc, left_on='Account_No', right_on='Acct_no')`

Comment: Thank you so much Zipa & Scott,  I have just started learning python and this platform is absolutely brilliant to post my doubts.